# NSWindow and setLevel, cant' get "on top" functionality working

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode

When two windows are close together you can snap them (window manager autocorrects windows position/sizes and snaps them together, see image attached)

[image]

NSWindows have levels:

```
[Window setLevel:kCGBaseWindowLevelKey]
```

I want window to be always on top and snap-able. I can achieve "on top" functionality by doing:

```
[Window setLevel:kCGScreenSaverWindowLevelKey];
```

However, now window is not snap-able. How can i have both, snap-able and "on top". I have tried every possible window level, only one level is snapable, that is kCGBaseWindowLevelKey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer.
**Two windows at the same place with different levels.**

It's possible to create an invisible window with window level kCGBaseWindowLevelKey and put it right below the window with kCGScreenSaverWindowLevelKey level. Two windows at the same place with different levels.

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSWindowStyleMask)windowStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)deferCreation
{
    if (self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO])
    {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    }
    
    return self;
}
```